# XPath newbie confusion

Tags: xpath, scrapy

New to XPath (via Scrapy) but have had some wonderful quick successes.  Stumped on this, however; here's the node I'm after:

```
<a href="/pg/gaa/main/ref=gorgz_merch_name_3?ie=UTF8&amp;gorgzin=B0002523QW&amp;isGorgonzolaFulfilled=0&amp;seller=A1YEWN0HLL15CJ">Blusterfields</a>
```

Seems like this should work based on my other experiments:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "gorgz_merch_name")]/text()').extract()
```

...but it returns zilch.

Oddly,

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, \'/pg/gaa/main\')]/text()').extract()
```

...*does* return "Blusterfields" (& the other items I'm after).  Which would be fine, I guess, but there's another datapoint I'm after:

```
<a href="/pg/gaa/main/ref=gorgz_merch_rating_3?ie=UTF8&amp;gorgzin=B0002523QW&amp;isGorgonzolaFulfilled=0&amp;seller=ASDFOASDFU><b>97% positive</b></a>
```

So the Xpath I'm using seems like it *should* catch both, but doesn't.  Not that I would want it to catch both, but this is just one more factor adding to my confusion.

Ideally I'd be catching the latter with something like:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "gorgz_merch_rating")]/text()').extract()
```

...but needless to say, that's not working either.

Any guidance / tips very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give link to the page and the actual spider code (or relevant part)?

Comment: Not sure I should-- I made some, ahem, subtle changes to the code above as I believe the actual entities robots.txt pretty much precludes any such activity.

Comment: It's html, & I tried removing namespaces anyway, so that's not it.  I was initially thinking the underscores might be XPath special characters, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Or that only so much of the href value could be searched.  However, replacing "isGorgonzolaFulfilled" for "gorgz_merch_name" results in success.

Comment: I've got an ungraceful workaround, but it seems like I'm missing an essential piece of knowledge which would allow me to find any given string in the @href value.  As it is, some work, some (the ones I'd prefer, naturally) don't; & that drives me a bit batty

Comment: Also, should mention-- I'm just running this in the Scrapy shell, so that really is all the code being applied, pretty much.

Comment: And looking at the raw responses, Scrapy simply isn't receiving the code I'm searching for.  I suspect it's Gorgonzola being very clever about making scraping difficult which is to blame here.

Comment: Indeed, this was the case.  Setting user agent to Lynx & all is well.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be something like that, because XPath expressions were valid and tested against your sample elements yielding correct output.